# what does $ mean in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was watching a video about object literals in JS. Then the guy in the video did something like this:

```
var Facebook = {
    name: 'Facebook',
    ceo: {
        firstName: "Mark",
        favColor: "Blue"
    },
$stock: 110
};
```

My question is why is there a $ sign in front of stock? Is there a special meaning? or did he just use it for naming purpose only? I entered $ in console and got something like this: 
`function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`

I understand that $ sign is used as a selector for JS libraries like JQuery, but what is it's significance in pure JS?

Comment: Reviewers should note that in this context, this is not a duplicate of the referenced question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a character. If you saw something in the console it's because some script loaded by that page assigned it a value and it was still in the global scope.

Sometimes (like with jQuery or Angular) it can get used by convention to denote that the value assigned to that variable or property is related to those libraries somehow.

In your example it's just the name of a property.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` has no special meaning in JavaScript. It's just a valid variable name. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/404556).

Comment: But can you explain why when you enter $ in console it returns a function!?

Comment: @Anonymous it's a debugging global that exists in the console only, as convenience for the verbose `document.querySelector()`

Comment: Literally just google ["Command Line API"](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference)

Comment: @Anonymous, `$` exists as a shortcut for `document.querySelector()`, but only in browsers (the name probably being `$` due to historic reasons and people used to it from jQuery). Try typing `$` in NodeJS -- `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.